# Adicionar Icon com React native Material UI Botão

Tags: react-native, icons, material-ui

Tenho esse botão com o ícone details, mas gostaria de colocar o expandmore que tem no material ui, porém, ao colocá-lo, não funciona, nenhum nome de icone que possui mais de uma palavra funciona

```
import {Icon} from 'react-native-material-ui';
<Button 
color="#598ac1"
width="17%"
height={23}
style={styles.details}
onPress={() => {this.addDescricao();}}>
<Icon name="details" size={20} color="white" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou te dar a sugestão de usar o

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'

  <Icon name='heart' size={30} color='white'/>
```

[Procure o ícone desejado nesse diretório](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)

Se necessário, mude do FontAwesome para o grupo desejado.
E não esqueça de fazer a instalação das dependências no seu projeto: 
`yarn add react-native-vector-icons` ou `npm i react-native-vector-icons`